# Duplicate a Prefab as a separate asset in Unity 5.2

Tags: unity, assets, gameobject

I have a Asset which is a collectable object [Pickup] and I currently have eight in my scene, I'd like to duplicate this asset and use it to harm the player [Bad Pickup].

I decided to duplicate the asset because I wanted both assets to have the same components (Animation script, rigid body, mesh colider, etc...). However, when I edit the texture of my new asset [Bad Pickup], it changes the texture used for the original asset [Pickup] as well.

I've tried GameObject -> Break Prefab Instance on the object with the new asset but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Is there a way to break this instance so that I don't have to make a completely new GameObject and add the same components manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're editing a material. Prefabs simply reference materials, they don't contain them. That material is used for both prefabs. You can duplicate the prefabs, but make sure you create a new material for any prefabs you want to have a different material.

Comment: I have two materials, I'm editing the material referenced by the Game Object.

Comment: And two textures?

Comment: Yes, two materials, referencing two separate textures

Comment: Then editing one wouldn't affect the other. It's likely you have misreferenced something somewhere.

Comment: I see now, I was editing the reference to a texture, not a material. It's working fine now. Also I agree, this looks like a duplicate of the question linked above, Thanks!